# How to adjust image size according to current resolution of screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to do something like this in CSS:

```
.addImage{
    background-image:url('imageURL');
    // This is where I have a query:
    background-size: get_current_length get_current_width;
}
```

Comment: have you tried `100vh` for length and `100vw` for width?

Comment: @MichaelCoker Thanks, I used that method and It worked. Thank you..

Comment: You're welcome. Since you have answers now, I'll go ahead and post it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [viewport units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Units) to get the current width/height of the page. Use `100vw` for 100% of the viewport width, and `100vh` for 100% the viewport height.

Answer (score 0):

I propose to use trick:

```css
img
{
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're asking, you have to be more clear but it seems to me, you want the image to scale with the browser resolution. If so you can use percentages to specify width and height.

```
.addImage {
    width: 100%;     
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can say:

```
.addImage
{
    background-image: url(URL);
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is background image,

```
.addImage {
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

if it is image,

```
.addImage {
    width: 100%;     
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this question(with help of stackoverflow) and here is my code:

```
.addBackgroundImage{

background-image:url('image_url');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-attachment: fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: 100vw 100vh;
-moz-background-size:  100vw 100vh;
-o-background-size: 100vw 100vh;
background-size: 100vw 100vh;
}
```